# how to post a photo and message to Facebook using the new Facebook GRAPH API on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, sdk, photo

I know how to post an image using the GRAPH API and I know how to post a comment using the same.  But I can't figure out how to post a photo and allow the user to also include a message/status with the photo (all posting on the user's own wall).

This is the code that I am using to upload a photo from my app to user's wall.  The GRAPH API does not define what other keys I can specify in the param dictionary.

```
-(void) uploadPhotoToFacebook {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   imageView.image, @"picture", nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                     andParams:params
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
}
```

I have found ways to do this using the now deprecated Facebook API but that doesn't help me.

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// Post a status update along with picture via the Graph API, and display an alert view 
with the results or an error.

```
NSString *message =  @"This is status Message!";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myPngImageToPost"];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:message, UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"message", @"picture", nil]];

// use the "startWith" helper static on FBRequest to both create and start a request, with
// a specified completion handler.
[FBRequest startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                 parameters:params
                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

              [self showAlert:message result:result error:error];
          }];
```

The above code will show status update as well as image below your status message.

Comment: It will create an album to add photos inside it and status messages are appended for each photos.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/ ...  along with the restrictions and required permissions.  I have been wrestling with it for a few days since not everything I expect to work works! For posting you want to use the "source" key instead of picture which refers to the thumbnail.

Posting on the wall (feed dialog) and comments (graph photo/comment) (comments and tags are adding connections) are all separate transactions. For posting, I'm struggling with it since I can post a photo by providing an existing URL from another website but for some reason, I cannot point use the photo link from the picture I just posted (the feed dialog appears without any photo).